# Set Flash Data Session using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have ajax code like this. I want to show my flashdata after reload (via JS)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{ URL::to('admin/deposit/ajaxapprove') }}", 
    data: mydata,
    success : function(result){
        //set_flashdata session
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

how to set flashdata session to show alert after reload page? i want to show the flashdata session on bootstrap alert..

Comment: Set flash message in php (Codeigniter)  and check it on reload if set then show the message

Comment: how to do it? sorry i dont understand

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353370/codeigniter-flash-data

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that --

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>
    <script>alert('ok');</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add more explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set flash message in codeigniter files

```
// load session library if not auto-loaded
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Category added');
```

When control return to you Ajax request it will reload the page
then check for flash message is set or not

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){ ?>
    //Here goes you bootstrap alert code
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think you are not understand what my question means, i just need set_flashdata but in javascript code, not at the php

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I did as the following method for a quick solution(javascript method).

```
<div class="col-md-12 alert-container"></div> <!-- alert container -->

$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "{{ URL::to('admin/deposit/ajaxapprove') }}", 
 data: mydata,
 success : function(result){
    var alert =`<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>Success message here </div>`;
    $('.alert-container').html(alert); /* alert container class ".alert-container" */
    setTimeout(function(){ /* show the alert for 3sec and then reload the page. */
      location.reload();
    },3000);
 }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.
The solution is simple. Under the success function you just type:

```
<?php $this->session->set_flashdata('msg-success',"//your messages here"); ?>
```